# Is this masonry roofline intersection problematic? Should it be called out by our home inspector?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, brick, masonry

Our new house (brick and stone veneer) came with a significant exterior wall leak at a roofline/masonry intersection, so I've been learning more about how these are supposed to be waterproofed, and am concerned similar intersections may have problems in the future.

Here's an example of an area of concern:[image: Roof masonry intersection]

Researching online, there are different techniques that can be used here, but they all seem to involve flashing that covers the bottom of the masonry. It's what I see on most houses in my neighborhood. But not on mine. :-/

Are there techniques for waterproofing that are legitimate where all of the flashing is behind the brick veneer? Or is what is shown here suspect?

Comment: I always use step flashing on a wall like that but there may be other ways I don't know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this truly a brick veneer wall (one full brick deep), or an "adhered" brick veneer (1/4" - 1/2" thick)?  A brick veneer wall should definitely have visible flashing, counter-flashing, and weep holes, but an adhered veneer might just have flashing behind the joint.  I do see that the roof bulges along the joint, this is a good sign that there is something there, but it does not look like proper flashing.  There should also be flashing visible below the adhered veneer. (see http://ncma-br.org/pdfs/masterlibrary/MVMA%20Installation%20Guide%204th%20Edition%20web.pdf pages 28,29,36).

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is one full brick deep, as that is what most of the house is. I suppose there is a small possibility that the builder found thin brick veneer that matched the full brick, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @ironeagle Wow great reference details.

Comment: @aggieNick02 true, I just thought that the mortar joint along the roof made it look a little more like thin veneer, but if they are full brick I wonder what it is they are resting on.  This whole situation seems like one any building inspector would raise their eyebrows at.

Comment: So from looking at the place where we had our water damage, they are likely full thickness and resting on triple 2x4s; while my reading has told me this is discouraged, it seems not uncommon in my area (central Texas).

Comment: Also interesting from tearing apart the damaged area, still ongoing - the hump you see is flashing. The brick/stone sits on top of flashing that extends far out under the shingles and then up the wall. Every installation guide I've seen calls for visible flashing/counterflashing, but even the waterproofing company I've hired, who has been doing this stuff exclusively for 30+ years, says the technique is solid... we've yet to get to the point on the damage tear-open to find the root cause.

Comment: @IronEagle, thanks for the detailed installation guide for thin veneer. I understand that technique, and am trying to understand why just standard waterproofing with heavy duty flashing, like is used with hardiplank, is not sufficient for masonry? I imagine there is a reason, I just don't see it with my lack of understanding.

Comment: @aggieNick02 - Houses breathe. In colder weather, moisture from the warm air inside the house hits the outer side of a frame wall and can condense.  In the case of hardiplank, that water is let out down through each joint.  Brick veneer, not being that open, will have through- or normal flashing and weep holes to let any water behind the wall out. Thin Veneer will usually have a space or weep screed behind it for the same purpose, or will be directly applied to a masonry wall. My grandfather actually built a house in the 1950's, and sealed it too well, leading to the full exterior rotting.

Comment: @IronEagle - that makes sense, thanks. My confusion though is why the masonry on roofline calls for counterflashing to keep the first couple bricks dry instead of just calling for flashing behind the lowest brick that runs up and behind the waterproofing, if that makes sense? Perhaps to allow for weep holes that are not at a level where water will be streaming by?

Comment: Also interesting, no houses in the neighborhoods around here have the flashing technique advocated in most places online, which results in basically a stair-step of flashing visible at the roofline. Instead, most appear to have opted for reglet counterflashing,

Comment: @aggieNick02 - that seems right.

Comment: Thanks @IronEagle. My waterproofer generally doesn't believe weepholes are as important as other details of the installation, so I guess that explains his point of view. That's probably a somewhat controversial opinion but a little googling makes it seem like he's not completely alone, for what it's worth.